# Given a sequence of symbols, how to find the minimal DFA that can accept it?

Tags: regex, pattern-matching, regular-language, fsm, dfa

For example: Given the below symbol sequence,

```
a b c b c d d d b c b c d d d d e
```

The simplest DFA that can accept it is a chain of 17 states.

While the below regular expression can derive the above sequence:

```
a (b c)* (d)* (b c)* (d)* e
```

And the corresponding minimal DFA has 8 states.

Further, the regular expression `a ((b c)* (d)*)* e` has even smaller minimal DFA with 4 states. And it can accept the example sequence.

In the above example, I only considers the `*` operator; More general, operator `|` can also be considered to reduce the DFA size.

So, the general question is:

Given a sequence of symbols, how to find the minimal DFA that can accept it?

Comment: Are you looking for the minimal DFA that accepts _only_ the sequences described by the regex?

Comment: @cheeken: such a DFA would necessarily have to have exactly as many states as the sequence, since any reuse of states could be repeated to generate other strings.

Comment: @nneonneo I don't disagree, though my question pertains to DFAs describing regexes, not a particular sequence.  I'm hoping JackWM can clarify his question, because I feel he mightn't be asking what he means to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy. A DFA with one state can always do it. That one state is a start state, accepting state, and all symbol transitions loopback into it. That trivial DFA accepts all strings (∑*), and is definitely the smallest-possible DFA.

Answer (score 2):

1. Regular expression -> NFA
2. Then NFA -> DFA
3. Then DFA -> Minimal DFA

There are bunch of algorithms online that you can google for each step.
And you can check your DFA/NFA.
http://hackingoff.com/compilers/regular-expression-to-nfa-dfa